# While "editing" an LINQ to SQL entity, can I simply assign one item to another?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, relational-database, editing

To be clear, let's say I have this code:

```
void AlterItem(Orderable o) {  
    foreach(Orderable p in from Orderable n in dataContext.Orderables 
            where n.UID == o.UID 
            select n)  
    p = o;  
    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Of course this code does not work, because you cannot assign to an iterational variable, this is clear for me. Is there any way better than rewriting particular fields? I tried Single() but after assigning one variable to another it does not apply changes.

Sorry if this was asked before. I did my efforts to find the answer and failed.

Answer (score 1):

No, aside from the `foreach()` parameter problem a simple `p = o;` would only copy  a reference.

The best thing is to write code to copy properties, maybe with the use of AutoMapper.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a confusion between variables and objects. With the following, all that happens is that the variable `p` refers to the same object as the `o` parameter instead of the return object from `dataContext.Orderables.First()`. When you submit changes, nothing is actually submitted because none of the database objects were changed. Only a reference was changed:

```
void AlterItem(Orderable o)
{
   var p = dataContext.Orderables.First();
   p = o;
   dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

In order to change the object returned from `dataContext.Orderables.First()` you have to change its properties. You can also modify the object via a `foreach` variable this way:

```
var p = dataContext.Orderables.First();
p.Property1 = o.Property1;
// etc...
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```